# React Native: can't a method be used from 'routeMapper'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

I’m using react native drawer of https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer

I am trying to call the method openDrawer() by passing in variable into NavigationBarRouteMapper. I tried logging inside NavigationBarRouteMapper, and it logs the variable passed in correctly. But when it used inside the NavigationBarRouteMapper, by clicking the Left Navigation button of ‘Open Drawer’, it does not do anything:

```
class drawerPractice extends Component {
...

  openDrawer(){
    this._drawer.open()
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <Drawer
    content={<DrawerPanel/>}
    openDrawerOffset={100}
    ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
    type='static'
    tweenHandler={Drawer.tweenPresets.parallax}
  >
        <Navigator
          configureScene={this.configureScene}
          initialRoute={{name: 'Start', component: Start}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          style={styles.container}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              style={styles.navBar}
              routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper(this.openDrawer)}
            />
          }
        />
  </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = openDrawer => ({
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
      return(
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{openDrawer}}>
              <Text>Open Menu</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    }
  },...
```

Why may be the issue?

Comment: Did you check the error logs? My guess is you'd be getting an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes that's exactly it! Why is it doing so and how can I go about resolving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `constructor()` method add this: `this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);`

You're likely using `this` on the wrong scope.

Comment: I tried it out before but still it is not being activated... It is correctly logging the openDrawer() function though -- tried it inside LeftButton function in NavigationBarRouteMapper. Everyone is correct but so confused as to why it isn't working

Comment: I don't know much on NavigationBar, so I'm looking for other things. I think your `onPress` method is doing nothing though, should be `<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> openDrawer}>` to return the method or `<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{ openDrawer() }}>` to execute it.

Comment: Yes!!! openDrawer() worked!!!! thank you so much. been stressing about this all day yesterday and today. You the savior

Comment: One more question if you don't mind :D. How can I pass in navigator={navigator} like so into the component <DrawerPanel/> in the content property of <Drawer/>? I tried <DrawerPanel navigator={navigator}/> and logged this.props inside DrawerPanel but it is not getting the right navigator.

Comment: Create a `_navigator` variable outside your class, then, on your `renderScene` method, you'll receive the current `navigator` as a parameter. You can do `_navigator = navigator` and then access it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry but do you mind showing an example of it? I attempted the following:   renderScene(route, navigator){ this._navigator = navigator return(...)} and did <Drawer content={< DrawerPanel navigator={this._navigator} /> ... </ Drawer > but in the renderScene got the following error: 'Can't add property _navigator, object is not extensible'. Is that the right approach? What may be the issue?

Comment: Let's discuss this on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519655/how-to-pass-navigator-reference-to-react-native-drawer/

Answer (score 2):

There is a common confusion when working with React components and the new ES6 `extends` syntax. If you use `React.createClass`, it will bind `this` to all of your functions, but when using the ES6 approach of `extends React.Component` you have to bind your functions manually.

You can do it either inline using

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.openDrawer.bind(this)}}>
```

Alternatively, you can add to your constructor, after `super()`:

```
this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
```

Personally I like this approach as I find this code a bit easier to read.

For more information about the ES6 way, check [this link](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/).

Comment: Hello again Kuf! I tried the second approach but it doesn't do anything when I click the left nav button... like I do not get any errors either. It is just not opening.

Comment: and just to confirm, you meant this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this), correct?

Comment: @JoKo yea sure.. copied from my code and forgot to update. I'll try your code later and see if I can add anything

Comment: One more question if you don't mind :D. How can I pass in navigator={navigator} like so into the component <DrawerPanel/> in the content property of <Drawer/>? I tried <DrawerPanel navigator={navigator}/> and logged this.props inside DrawerPanel but it is not getting the right navigator.