# How to pass navigator reference to React Native <Drawer/>?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

Using react-native-drawer ( https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer ) in my index.ios.js, I have the following set up and trying to pass 'navigator' reference into content's < DrawerPanel /> of < Drawer />. I console.log(this.props.navigator) in < DrawerPanel /> but a wrong navigator reference is passed in, when I am attempting to do similar to this.props.navigator.replace() inside < DrawerPanel />

How can I pass in the right navigator constructor like that of being passed into renderScene and configureScene? :

```
class practice extends Component {
    ...
    renderScene(route, navigator){
        ...
    }

    configureScene(route, routeStack){
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Drawer
            content={<DrawerPanel navigator={navigator}/>}
            ...
          >
            <Navigator
              configureScene={this.configureScene}
              initialRoute={{name: 'Login', component: Login}}
              renderScene={this.renderScene}
              style={styles.container}
              navigationBar={
                <Navigator.NavigationBar
                  style={styles.navBar}
                  routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper(this.openDrawer)}
                />
              }
            />
         </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE 3****

In my `<DrawelPanel/>`

```
import HomePage from './HomePage'

render(){

var pr = this.props
var navigator = pr.getNav()

return (
    <View style={{flex:1, padding: 30, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <MadeButton 
            componentName={HomePage}
            navigator={navigator}
            pageName='HomePage'
            style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold', color:'white'}}
        />
    </View>
)
```

Then in my `<MadeButton/>`

```
  static propTypes = {
    componentName: React.PropTypes.any,
    navigator: React.PropTypes.any,
    pageName: React.PropTypes.string,
    style: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  _navigate(type='Normal'){
    this.props.navigator.replace({
      component: this.props.componentName,
      type: type,
      name: this.props.pageName
    })
  }

  render(){
    var pr = this.props;
    var st = this.state;
    var styles = pr.style;

    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._navigate()}>
        <Text style={styles}>{pr.pageName}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done. You save the navigator reference form `renderScene` method define a getter method, pass the method to the component you want.

```js
class practice extends Component {
    ...
    renderScene(route, navigator){
        this._navigator = navigator
    }

    configureScene(route, routeStack){
        ...
    }
     
    getNav = () => {
      return this._navigator
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Drawer
            content={<DrawerPanel getNav={this.getNav}/>}
            ...
          >
            <Navigator
              configureScene={this.configureScene}
              initialRoute={{name: 'Login', component: Login}}
              renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
              style={styles.container}
              navigationBar={
                <Navigator.NavigationBar
                  style={styles.navBar}
                  routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper(this.openDrawer)}
                />
              }
            />
         </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but in the renderScene() got the following error: 'Can't add property _navigator, object is not extensible'. What may be the issue?

Comment: `this` is not bound by default. you need to do `renderScene={(route, navigator) => renderScene(route, navigator)}`. I have updated the example to reflect the change.

Comment: @AakashSigdel Gotcha. So inside the renderScene I have the following:     `this._navigator = navigator

    return (
        <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
    )` and inside < DrawerPanel /> I `console.log(this.props)` and the navigator now comes out to be undefined `Object {navigator: undefined}`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @AakashSigdel No worries but please take a look at my original post with updated code. I tried console.log in DrawerPanel but it does not log the proper prop of navigator that allows you to do as such, this.props.navigator.replace(). What may be the issue?

Comment: That is because, when the this_navigator = navigator is execute, the prop to the DrawerPanel is already passed, and without setting the state the re-rendered doesn't occur, so no new porp is passed, hence undefined. The getter approach I have mentioned in the update works, as the function is always in the scope of the navigator, so it can get the navigator when you call it form DrawerPanel. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @AakashSigdel Yes thanks for the clarification! Please take a look at my second update to see what I'm doing in the original post. So I passed the navigator down to < DrawerPanel /> and down to < MadeButton /> and tried this.props.navigator.replace(), but got an error that 'this.props.navigator.replace is not a function'. The way you explained it, everything makes sense but really confused to why it isn't it working...

Comment: @AakashSigdel Just checking to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. I have written a next answer for this second update below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong. If you use ,  should not has the same parent node with .

```
const Drawer = <Drawer
                  content={<DrawerPanel navigator={navigator}/>}
                  ...
               />
<Navigator
  initialRoute={{ name: 'Drawer', component: Drawer }}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
  configureScene={(route) => {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump;
  }}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
    let Component = route.component;
    return <Component {...route.params} navigator={navigator} />
   }} />
  }
/>
```

Comment: I added more details in the original post. Please take a look. Is it truly done incorrectly? I was informed that that's how it was supposed to be set up.

Comment: I know what you meant! I think maybe the `<Drawer  />` it is not a container that can use `Navigator `. just like the model can not use ScrollView in 0.17.0

Comment: Then how could I go about using functions such as this.props.navigator.replace() in < DrawerPanel >?

Answer (score 0):

In update 2, you have done: `var navigator = pr.getNav`. This only assigns getNav function to the navigator variable you just defined. So your navigator here is just a reference to the getNav function.

What you need to do is `var navigator = pr.getNav()` and then pass the navigator to `MadeButton`. Hope is clarify things.

Comment: Ah got it. Tried it as suggested but got the error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. So I tried `console.log(this.props.navigator)` in `MadeButton` but got `undefined`. Don't know if this may be the issue, but this is how I call the navigator.replace in `MadeButton`: `<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._navigate()}>...</TouchableHighlight>` and in _navigate(), `this.props.navigator.replace({...})`.

Comment: Are you getting the navigator object on DrawerPanel after doing the getNav(). Also could you update the question as well?

Comment: I updated the original post with the updated code under UPDATED 3****. Please take a look. There's an extremely weird case. At times, via pr.getNav() the navigator is fetched correctly and the `<MadeButton/>` navigates correctly. But at times, when the simulator is refreshed, the navigator is undefined so the `<MadeButton/>` gets an error: `Cannot read property "replace" of undefined`. I am confused as to what could possibly be the error...

Comment: just checking in again to see if you've seen my previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: Could you let me know if you've seen my previous comment?